# y-axis show and hide functionality in chart js not working in angular 6

Tags: javascript, charts, angular6, chart.js, angular2-template

I want to show and hide y-axis on clicking the legends in x-axis. but the condition is that I have different chart values each time I select a value. 
so the y axis does not changes its functionality of show and hide.

```
 setValue(chartValue) {
    var n

    if (chartValue== "a") {
      n = 6
    }

    if (chartValue== "b") {
      n = 4
    }
    if (chartValue== "c") {
      n = 8
    }

    Chart.plugins.register({
      beforeDraw: function (c) {
        var canvas_id = c.chart.canvas.id;
        if (canvas_id === 'myChart') {
          console.log("chart val>>", n)
          for (var ii = 0; ii < 4; ii++) {
            if (!c.isDatasetVisible(ii)) {
              c.options.scales.yAxes[ii].display = false;
            } else c.options.scales.yAxes[ii].display = true;
          }


        }
      }
    });
  }
```

html :

```
<canvas id="myChart" style="display: block; width: 1415px; height: 550px;"></canvas>
```

the above code only runs on 1st instance. if I call the same function later on button click it does not work. I want It to work on various n values

Comment: what is your html code?